# JavaScript not working when using innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html

What is wrong with below code? I've added a button. And on the button's onclick event, I'm calling the script to change the value of p tag.

In the script, I'm trying to set the value od p tag using its ID attribute.

But nothing is changing if I click on the button.

Tested in different browsers, still no result.

**Here is the code:**

```
<HTML>
<BODY>
<INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" onclick="changeValue()" VALUE="Change Value" />
<P ID="demo">Initial Value</P>
<SCRIPT>
function changeValue() {
  document.getElementByID("demo").innerHTML="Value Changed"
}
</SCRIPT>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Also, you should be able to look in the browser debug console and see a script error reported there to give you a clue as to what's wrong.  That's how you find errors on your own.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is **getElementById** with a lower case **"d"**.

```
getElementById()
```

Note: JavaScript is case sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

```
function changeValue() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML="Value Changed";
}
```

You have the `"d"` in ID capitalized and add a `";"` at the end and try it :)

Answer (score 0):

All of these answers give you the answer to your question - the problem with your code is the "getElementByID" function should be "getElementById", as JavaScript (like almost every programming and scripting language) is case sensitive.  And technically, you should include a semicolon, but it will still work in this case without it.

Replace the  element with the following (as @user3739658 provided):

```
 function changeValue() {
   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML="Value Changed";
 }
```

Then of course you would need to call that function:

```
changeValue();
```

If you want to make it a dynamic function, pass these parameters:

```
 function changeValue(id, newValue) {
   document.getElementById(id).innerHTML=newValue;
 }
```

Then you could call it like this:

```
 <script>
   changeValue('element-id','This is the new value'); 
 </script>
```